# Why is the variable declared with "var" keyword inside a function scope not stored inside window object?

Tags: javascript

[snapshot of code inside chrome dev tools debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvjWc.png)

As seen from the above snapshot, the variable "age" exists in the local scope but outside the window object. Why does it happen? Is there any in-depth explanation to it.

I checked the values and scope state using chrome dev tools debugger.

Comment: All text should be available in text form in the question. You may add the screenshot as supplementary information after that. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3966456 for details.

Comment: If you taught yourself JavaScript, have a look at  [Variable Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/) in MDN's Javascript Guide. If in any doubt, note that variables declared using `var` are only made properties of the `window` object if they are in global code and not within a function body or module.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables do not show up as `window` properties. Local variables are variables defined in the scope of functions. On the other hand, global variables are available as properties of `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared under function have function scope only.

```
function myFunction() {
var localVar = "I am a local variable";
console.log(localVar); } // This will log: "I am a local variable

console.log(typeof localVar); // This will log: "undefined"
```

But, Variables declared with var at the global scope, however, do become properties of the window object in browsers, but this behavior doesn't apply to variables declared inside function scopes.